# Azure devops unable to write to build Tab summary page

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I have created an Azure DevOps task, that takes in a random HTML file and presents this in build tabs. I have been trying multiple options, and have decided to use ##vso[task.uploadsummary] or Write-VstsAddAttachment to append HTML to the summary page, instead of creating a custom tab!

Problem is that HTML is not getting appended to the Summary page, instead, it is added to an "Extensions" tab, not sure what I am doing wrong here, I have tested both of these methods

```
Write-VstsAddAttachment -Type "Distributedtask.Core.Summary" -Name "Result" -Path $HTMLFilePath

write-host "##vso[task.addattachment type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=What If Result;]$HTMLFilePath"
```

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Azure devops append HTML to the summary page, instead of creating a custom tab

I am afraid there is no such way to append HTML to the summary page instead of creating the extension tab at this moment.

Whether using `addattachment` or `uploadsummary`, a new extension tab will be created to display the file. This behavior is **by designed**. There is no way to fix it at present.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps：

[image]

Besides, if you just want this HTML to be added to the summary as an attachment, and do not need to display its content in the summary, you can consider publishing this file as an **artifact** to the Azure pipeline.